# Static routing is redirecting

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, ip, route

I have one PC with 192.168.x.135 as IP and 192.168.x.33 as gateway; and a Windows Server 2008 with the IP 192.168.x.33.
Now I want to route all packages with the destination 14.x.x.x to 127.x.x.x.
So I added this route :

[image: Screenshot of route print]

But the server is not forwarding the packages. Instead of that he is redirecting the packages like you can see here:

[image: Screenshot of Sniffing with Whireshark]

So why is the server not routing my packages ? :)

Comment: Do you really mean `127.0.0.1`? It is your computers localhost ip address, and it can not forward packet to another network.  How is the net `14.102.129.0` connected to the computer?

Comment: Please explain a bit more. Is your server is your gateway? 127.0.0.x is loopback scheme which is for localhost. as per your question what i understand u want to route all traffic distinct for 14.x.x.x to 127.0.0.x which is localhost and u want traffic from localhost to localhost, its a bit confusing.

Comment: @bangal 127.0.0.1 was just a route to test if the packages arrive. the second route (to 127.102.x.49) is what I want to do. Because I have a programm that is listening to this local loopback. And this programm will forward the packages to another network.

Comment: @FaisalSaleem Yes, the server is the gateway of the PC. and i want all traffic from 14.x.x.x to 127.102.x.49. Because there a programm will work with the packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The ICMP "redirect" message indicates that the gateway to which the
>   host sent the datagram is no longer the best gateway to reach the net
>   in question. The gateway will have forwarded the datagram, but the
>   host should revise its routing table to have a different immediate
>   address for this net.
>   http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/icmp/msg5.htm

You can not use the route command to forward a packet just to another interface of the same router/computer. It doesn't make sense and doesn't work. The interfaces and their associated ip addresses are automatically added to the routing table, the moment the interface comes up.

Routing basically means forwarding packet from one network to another network. And you achieve this by configuring the router to forward the packet to the next hop (another router) which will be the ip address of the directly connected router of the second network.

Please take your time to understand the basic routing concept: [Help me understand the 'ip route' command for cisco routers](https://serverfault.com/questions/171551/help-me-understand-the-ip-route-command-for-cisco-routers)

Comment: Thanks, so now I know I cant route it like that :D 
Do you also have another idea how I could forward the packages like I want ?